# "print" didn't print in qpython console

Tags: printing, android-5.0-lollipop, qpython

I am a new programmer and learning python with qpython3 on my cellphone(android lollipop),that always needs to use "print" statement,but there is problem with "print"  in the console:

```
print "hello"
  File "<stdin>",line 1
    print " hello"
SyntaxError :invalid syntax
```

please tell me something about that fundemental "print" in qpython3 so I can get out of this trouble.

Comment: are you using python 2.x or python 3.x, if python 3.x, you should be using print().

Comment: Yes! I am using qpython3 that should be python 3.x,I follow your advice and it works,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 you have to surround what's in the print with brackets.

```
print("hello world")
```

as apposed to the old way which was just

```
print "hello world"
```

Comment: Got it! I started with python 2.7  on laptop and I should learn these updates in python 3.0,thank you.